# Why won't it let me evolve to jolteon?

Tags: pokemon-go

So I have tried the cheat by naming them, which worked. The first time.

Stupid ol' me accidentally transferred my jolteon and now the cheat by renaming them doesn't work. And since then, I've evolved eevee 5 times, and haven't gotten jolteon.

Does anyone else know of a way, or why I can't evolve to jolteon?

Comment: There is only a chance that it will work. With the new update, the cheat might have been removed

Comment: There are reports of the naming easter egg only working *once*. If you want another Jolteon, you'll be relying on random chance again.

Comment: It worked for me incase of 1 Flareon, 1 Jolteon and 2 Vaporeons. Next (5th) time I tried *Pyro* it turned into another Vaporeon `-_-`

Comment: Also make sure to restart the game before evolving.

Answer (score 13):

The renaming easter egg works only once per type.

- Rainer (Vaporeon) x1
- Pyro (Flareon) x1
- Sparky (Jolteon) x1

After that its all random

Answer (score 1):

New information has come to light suggesting that this will work more than once. However to work a second time, you need to do the full set... So you can't *just* evolve Jolteons...

This [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vslur/how_the_eevee_naming_conventions_actually_work/) suggests that once you've done a set, you have to do another set, possibly in the same order you did the first set. Possibly with time between evolutions. It may also be that the latest patch has "fixed" this easter egg.

Comment: But the first person to comment in your Reddit source said it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

We had similiar problem. Daughter transfered "jolteon", then before she evolved the next Eeve she typed in "jolteon", but evolved a vaporeon. (good news) BUT.. So we signed out, signed back in, the next Eeve we tried "sparky" before evolving and it worked. We got a Jolteon back!
 I have to add something that may have effected us as well. I read the pokemon are effected by the enviroment. Meaning more water pokemon are found closer to rivers or lakes. The extra vapereon eeve was within 1/2 of a river. This latest jolteon was atleast 5 miles from a river.

Comment: You realize it's not impossible to randomly evolve into Jolteon, right?

Comment: This answer is confusing, how did you get the first jolteon? Did you use "Sparky" as well or did you get it randomly? The environment thing still hasn't been proven...